# Writing a file into a local PC using IP address in PHP

Tags: php, ip-address

How to create a PHP script that would create a file.txt on the local pc through an IP address, there is a given IP address and a port which I can pass through.

How could I achieve this?

Any help will be appreciated, thank so much.

Comment: Your question is confusing, but if you are asking if your server can write a file to your computer... the answer is yes, and there are a variety of means.  However, the absolute easiest manner is to run a service on your local machine that the external server can talk to... say using PHP + Apache.

Comment: I think unless the PC has an FTP server, you can't do it.. If you set up an FTP on the PC, a quick google search will tell you how to transfer a file through FTP.

Answer (score 2):

You can either, FTP it to the local machine, or simply let a person download it as a file. The second solution is the easiest, but requires someone on the local machine to initiate the download. The first solution can be automated, but requires you to set up an FTP server on the local machine.

Header will help you output as a download for the client.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

FTP will help you upload through FTP.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php

Comment: Wow, thanks for the immediate response, here is the big picture. I want my php script to write/read a file programatically which is hosted on the net, which will access a folder on the Local PC, an IP address is provided and a port number. How could I achieved this without any downloading aid.

Comment: @EricPapas if you could place random files on people's computers without them having anything running on their PC to help, then the internet would be a very dangerous place. what you are talking about is not possible without something on the local PC that can read the socket and write the file on their end. FTP is the way to go here. It's pretty simple to install an FTP server. Much simpler than writing your own socket server daemon for the local PC to run.

Comment: If the server that PHP is running on is on the same network, and the folder you want to write to is available on the network, you can just write to the file system if you have permissions.

Comment: wait, when you say local PC, do you mean the server that PHP is running on? because that would change everything.

Answer (score 0):

on linux:

```
cat >dooda.php <<EOF
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php 
  file_put_contents('file.txt',file_get_contents("http://example.com/of_some_url.txt"));
EOF

php dooda.php
```